# How do I update my ng-grid from external sorting function

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Anyone know how to get ng-grid to update from an external sort function?

I've got userExternalSort set to true.  Then, I have this code (Coffeescript):

```
$scope.$on 'ngGridEventSorted', (event, data) ->
    console.log "Before sort " + $scope.recs[0].location

    $scope.recs.sort (a, b) ->
        if data.directions[0] = "asc"
            return a.location > b.location ? 1 : -1
        else
            return a.location > b.location ? -1 : 1

    console.log "After sort " + $scope.recs[0].location
```

My function actually does sort.  However, ng-grid never updates.  I've tried $scope.$apply() to no avail -- it's already in a $apply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

there's a couple problems with your code, and to help you fully with your code, I'll need to see your gridOptions, so that I can see whether you're updating the data properly or not. It might also help if we could get a plunkr with some code too

first thing is that the option is "useExternalSort" and that will actually turn off the ngGridEventSorted event, so you will need to use something like this instead:

```
$scope.$watch 'gridOptions.ngGrid.config.sortInfo', (newVal,oldVal) ->
    console.log "Before sort " + $scope.recs[0].location

    $scope.recs.sort (a, b) ->
        if data.directions[0] = "asc"
            return a.location > b.location ? 1 : -1
        else
            return a.location > b.location ? -1 : 1

    console.log "After sort " + $scope.recs[0].location
```

Comment: Thank you for the proper watch statement, you are literally the only person whose has gotten that right.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, and I seem to encounter a problem. I see that it goes inside the function the first time the grid loads but not when I click on the column heading. I have a [Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HnHunJ?p=preview). Is there something wrong in my setup?

Comment: For those who still wonder how to make sortInfo object to be updated, you need to watch with the 2nd "true" parameter to check the object by its value/content. Hope it helps.